# How does the angle between tangent vectors of a curve at different points and a given fixed uniform vector field change on rotation of curve?

Tags: geometry, definite-integrals, 3d, vector-fields, solid-geometry

I have to evaluate an integral  $\int B\ dl \sin\theta$  for  quarter $CD$ of the given ring of radius $r$. 
[$\theta$ being angle between tangent vector($d\vec l$) and $\vec B$]
[image: given ring]

1. **In the case where $\vec B$ was parallel to plane of ring:**

[image: parallel case]

(the arrows on the ring represent direction of tangent vectors to be taken)
The integral becomes $\int B\ dl \sin\theta=\int B\ r\sin\theta \ d\theta$ as change in $\theta$ is equal to in angle subtended by $dl$ 
The limits of integration for $\theta$ from C to D were $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. 
 This I figured easily using geometry.

2. **In case when $\vec B$ was perpendicular to plane of ring:**
   Value of integral becomes $B\sin(\pi/2)\int dl$ since $\vec B$ is perpendicular to tangent everywhere.
3. **In case when ring is rotated about its diameter by an angle**  such that
   **Ring is now inclined at an angle $\phi$ to vector field $\vec B$**
   This was the general case but I could not imagine nor draw a diagram to find the values of angle between $d\vec l$ and $\vec B$.
   ***For the third case***

- Can you provide a diagram or explanation of some sort to show how $\theta$ changes from $C\rightarrow D$?
- Is the angle between area($\vec A$) and $\vec B$ equal to $\cfrac{\pi}{2}-\phi$?
- What are the limits of integration and how will I relate $r\ $,$dl\ $,$B\ $,$\phi\ $,$\theta\ $ to compute the integral ?